# How to get all image, pdf and other files links from a web page?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nokogiri, hpricot

I have to develop a Ruby on Rails application which fetches all the images, pdf, cgi, etc. file extension links from web page.

Comment: Begin with reading `Net::HTTP` doc.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev 

thanks :) 

if you could let us know which method or function in Net::HTTP seems to much useful.. then it would be big help for me :)

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way to grab links from pages is to use [`URI.extract`](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/uri/1.9.2/URI#extract-class_method). From the docs:

> Description
>
> Extracts URIs from a string. If block given, iterates through all matched URIs. Returns nil if block given or array with matches.
>
> Usage

```
require "uri"

URI.extract("text here http://foo.example.org/bla and here mailto:test@example.com and here also.")
# => ["http://foo.example.com/bla", "mailto:test@example.com"]
```

Looking at this page:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'uri'

html = open('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722693/how-to-get-all-image-pdf-and-other-files-links-from-a-web-page/8724632#8724632').read

puts URI.extract(html).select{ |l| l[/\.(?:gif|png|jpe?g)\b/]}
```

which returns:

```
http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png
http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png
http://foobar.com/path/to/file.gif?some_query=1
http://pixel.quantserve.com/pixel/p-c1rF4kxgLUzNc.gif
```

Comment: Thanks for such clear and lucid explanation.

but when i try [http://testasp.vulnweb.com](http://testasp.vulnweb.com)

it doesnt return anything :(

Comment: There is one image in the page and it uses a relative `src`, which is why `URI.extract` can't find it. It expects a true URL. Nokogiri makes it easy to extract only the image tags: `doc.search('img')` will return a list of `img` nodes. Extract the `src` attribute and you're done.

Comment: Can you please help me in correcting the above code that is how Can I make that relative url to absolute url and I do have to search all the file extensions like pdf,css and etc.. so I am not using `doc.Searcj('img')` of nokogiri

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried the following tutorials to learn how to parse a web page first:

- [Nokogiri](http://railscasts.com/episodes/190-screen-scraping-with-nokogiri)
- [Mechanize](http://railscasts.com/episodes/191-mechanize)

Also, just as a note, be careful what sites you parse. It seems like getting all those PDF, images, etc. might be noticed by the site you are trying to parse.  I learned the hard way.

Sometimes you might be able to get info from feeds. Try this:

[Feed Parsing](http://railscasts.com/episodes/168-feed-parsing)

Comment: Thanks :)

Have you any idea that how any site-admin/web-master can detect/notice that such files are parsed?

Comment: @user1027702 not sure i think they blacklist your ip or something. A while back i tried to scrape info from a site and next thing i could not access the site. Its best always to check with the webmaster to see if it is ok to scrape info.

Answer (score 3):

Forget Net::HTTP, Open::URI is much easier. Here's some code to get you started:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

url = 'http://www.google.com/'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
doc.traverse do |el|
    [el[:src], el[:href]].grep(/\.(gif|jpg|png|pdf)$/i).map{|l| URI.join(url, l).to_s}.each do |link|
        File.open(File.basename(link),'wb'){|f| f << open(link,'rb').read}
    end
end
```

Comment: thanks :) 

I'm a newbie with ruby/rails can you please explain me where the above code stores results?

Comment: It saves the files in the current directory.

Comment: It's a big help for me :)
thanks :)

Comment: @ pguardiario 

your above code works fine but instead of only `gif|jpg|png|pdf` files, Can I grep any extensioned file? 

I mean need your much help in getting all type of files in webpage :)

Comment: Yes, you would just adjust the regex for whatever file extensions you are interested in

Comment: This was just what I was looking for. I just added a simple `pages.each` around it (where `pages` is an array of 17 urls I need scanned) and it's working like a charm this very moment!